# How can I give away a free copy of my paid Android app?

Tags: android

I am an app developer and I have a paid Android app in the market. I'd like to give one free copy to a specific person. Is this possible to do, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I know is to have the person purchase it, and then process a refund. Unfortunately, you'll have to do the process again if you publish any updates (or if the person wipes their phone).

That, or you can send the APK file to the person, although again this is something that needs to be done per update.

Comment: If you refund with out cancelling the order - will they not stil get updates?

Comment: No, a refund means that the person no longer owns the app, and as such is not eligible to updates. However, the app will remain on the phone. At least this is how I remember it.

Comment: I'm guessing the refund approach wont work with the Market licensing service.

Comment: You can always use this library: http://zemariamm.posterous.com/using-coupons-to-giveaway-paid-android-apps and give away coupons for full featured apps

Answer (score 0):

Just give them the apk...

Comment: thats what I do, email the apk and tell them please don't share it with anyone.  would be nice if google introduced coupons or something in the future.

Comment: You could give them a copy with their name prominently displayed in it...  (Note, by the way that giving them an apk requires that they enable non market sources, or use the SDK or "sideload wonder machine" to install over usb, the last two being the only choices for users of some current AT&T devices which lack the unkown sources menu option)

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to create promotion codes, which can be used to give your app or any of its IAPs away for free. See [documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6321495).